# Extracting values from String[] that has a pattern

Tags: java

I will use examples to explain this. I have two fields. Summary and Labels. An example of Labels would be `Labels = " QWE,CD-YTO, YTOU"` and `Summary = "CD-YTO : Some random words"`.

Now my code first checks labels  for any element that starts with "CD-" and if its present it, that's pretty much it. It takes that value, for example here it takes "CD-YTO". Now, in case labels does not have any element that starts with "CD-" then its supposed to check summary. That's where my problem lies.

The code i developed converts summary to an `String[]` by using `.split(" ")` and the just check for `.contains("CD-")`. but the code complexity increased and i was told to reduce it.
Summary can be like the following

```
"CD-YTO: Some random words"
"CD-RTY:Some random words"
"CD-RTUU Some random words"
"cd-GFY - Some random words"
```

Now, in all the above cases, im supposed to get the "CD-***" part only. Using if loop for all these cases just increases the code complexity. Is there any way i can reduce that?

Comment: How are we supposed to improve or reduce your code without seeing it? Please share the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is for loop, you can try to do the following:

```
String[] result  = Arrays.stream(yourString.split(" "))
    .filter(str -> str.contains("CD-"))
    .toArray();
```